# Should my iOS app have a keyboard shortcut for "edit", and if so, what should it be?

Tags: ios, keyboard-shortcuts

I am implementing keyboard shortcuts into a iOS app.

Some of the shortcuts I currently have:

Switching tabs: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + 1,2,3,4
Adding items: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
Search: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**Should I add a shortcut that enables the "Edit" button? If so, what should it be?**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's obvious that F4 should be used for Edit, and F6 for Rename (or whatever your equivalent is). Because that's how [Norton Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander) did it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I hope that is a joke.

Comment: Maybe CMD + E? It's simple and not a standard shortcut system wide.

Comment: Seriously: how are we supposed to know whether your app should have a keyboard shortcut for "edit"? I have flagged this for community attention as "primarily opinion-based", and it is pending review as such. Is there any way you can edit your question to allow answers to be based more in fact than in opinion?

Comment: The app got a help section. Including tips and tricks about keyboard shortcuts for pro users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are making an app for an iPhone, I would not have a keyboard short cut for edit, this adds in unnecessary steps as the keyboard is generally hidden inside an app so you are asking your user to bring up the keyboard and press key combinations. Whereas the edit button on the app is just one tap and is quick enough as it is.

If you are making an app for use of an iMac or Macbook etc, there are not any default setting that I can see that are already in use.